# Finding the correct permutation of spaces and underscores in a string, in PHP

Tags: php

I have to parse a XFERLOG log file of all the files being written to disk, and process the said files with an external script. The issue with XFERLOG is that it replaces all spaces with  underscores, while the filename on disk remains unchanged (as it should be).

If the original filename has a mix of spaces and underscores, this situation makes it difficult to determine the actual filename on disk, so one would have to loop through all the permutations of spaces and underscores, check each permutation again the filesystem to see if it exists.

So lets say the logfile reads this:

```
/path/to/file/OCD_Nightmare_-_[stuff_here_2].txt
```

The actual file on disk looks like this:

```
/path/to/file/OCD Nightmare - [stuff_here 2].txt
```

There is 2^5 permutations here. What would be the best course of action to find the "right" string?

Comment: Why can't you simply use a regular expression as filter against a file listing? The result will be a single match. That is the name you are looking for.

Comment: I was hoping not to get into listing individual dirs, but just using the native file_exists() function on each attempt

Comment: Sure, but that means one access per attempt to the file system, whilst otherwise you need only one single access. You can guess which is more effective and performs better...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly use str_replace for this:

```
if(str_replace('_', ' ', $filename) == str_replace('_', ' ', $logfilename))
{
    //Yay, a match!
}
```

Note: As mentioned in a comment below, if your filesystem has `/path/to/file/OCD_Nightmare_-_[stuff_here_2].txt` and `/path/to/file/OCD_Nightmare -_[stuff here_2].txt`, they will both match the log entry of `/path/to/file/OCD Nightmare - [stuff_here 2].txt`, possibly resulting in unwanted behavior.  I believe this may be a very unlikely situation, but still worth noting.

Comment: what if u have 'file_like this.exe' and 'file like_this.exe' it will match both but they not the same file, just a thought...

Comment: Agree, you get the same name in both sides quickly, XD

Comment: That looks like a caveat of his situation.  Since his log file (presumably) strips underscores in file names, this is a natural consequence.

Comment: you might want to check this: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_ExtendedLog.html and : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.proftpd.user/5604

Comment: Good find on the extendedlog! Will check it out!